# Vba Excel Formula for following condition(Circular Referencing)

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

---

Hi, i tried to put a formula like `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=""India"",RC,"""")"` If the country is not **India** then Check1, Check2 and Check3 should be empty otherwise they should display their own value. when i tried to put that formula the excel has given me circular referencing warning. I just want that formula. Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 0):

When a formula refers back to its own cell, either directly or indirectly, it creates a circular reference.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=""India"",RC,"""")"
```

You are writing the formula in activecell and the formula says if **RC[-1]="India"**
and if its true **RC** which is same as activecell. Hence you are getting the circular reference error.

But if you put this formula in **Column E** as below it would work.

```
Range("E2:E" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-4]=""India"",RC[-3],"""")"
```

Alternatively below is simple VBA code.

```
Sub sample()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If (InStr(1, Cells(i, 1), "India") <= 0) Then
            Range("B" & i & ":D" & i).Clear
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @Santhosh,At any time RC will have a default value. If RC[-1]="India" then it should display it's own value otherwise it should display empty. this is what my requirement is.

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** use `RC` as a result only as this is referencing the current formula.

**Option 1:** You need to have another cell to be the validated cell, e.g.the following will create a cell to the left one of the current cell:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]=""India"",RC[-1],"""")"
```

**Option 2 after comment:** If your line of code is only going to clear the current cells value if the left cell is not **India** then use this:

```
If ActiveCell.Offset(0,-1).Value <> "India" Then ActiveCell.Value = ""
```

**Option 3:** If your default value in RC has to stay but a formula is needed to override it if the value of RC[-1] becomes a not equal to **India** you must hard code your value in the formula like so:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=""India"",""" & ActiveCell.Value & ""","""")"
```

Comment: Actually that RC has it's own value by default. when we apply the above formula in **TRUE** case the RC will take first left cell's value that's fine but in **FALSE** case the RC should display it's default value. In your formula you are making empty in else case.

Comment: Where is the default value stored? Or do you want to only override this RC value if  true?

Comment: I want to only override this RC value if true. I have understood your logic `If ActiveCell.Offset(0,-1).Value <> "India" Then ActiveCell.Value = ""` but i want that should be as a formula. thanks for quick response.

Comment: Also, you can't have a value and a formula in a cell at the same time, this just becomes a formula with a hardcoded vale. Hope this helps.